# RSA / RS256 Encryption with the public key I have

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key

safe to say I'm a complete beginner when it comes to cryptography... I believe the example output below is some sort of RSA (or RS256) encrypted string, and was just curious whether it'd be possible to re-create that encryption with any random text I enter based on the information that I have below.

*Example output (what I'm trying to achieve):*

```
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
```

*What I assume to be the "public key"?:*

```
"publicKey": {
    "prefix": "EAAQ",
    "jwk": {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "n": "24gKlX5n_yeOKYOyAQ4LCiZtzWrhU3SoHfHBVEYufsMvSA_BQ8M985Foj-LWuM3NleRJVTPptfaVS8Oryr5RYlNYxOtUcUw5MeVBbkSRr8k56NY4mN7XTAPHwvol2ZeFUWhPJrzEmvN-eiU1TXJF1lqe0CDoYILjb5oAcGzjiPyfUsxYokCR7AWytdIrqjmqqN9QoBiB1QdpABCEwmBFh5owOhOrm8l_V9KGScd0-hAXYr-uJrGqh12EUhmc5AL5jZPxtYvdTmutVZOwXhfNC1ywIjdsGBnsCKPRlcUunf_J-NbRiPKVepsTGFbu7QrurSmXN_-moBZ_unG4WQSpk0RDoFazf7L0X2bIyL1vj7HT3x-IB0F6nKCLiKeUBncxFgbgit2TGEf5IbscFMVMCscTQBjh4F_zUw1d1u2DKAvXsrylhk2D3X9T4NM6Bypb-zU0mKVXMv-gMaoYEknOm_prohDvY1idfkf0cqhlkEkV7Fe6cV4MxHxuR0ig3yvHjEu5BvO1Slhtc_uumZvHKfhC_4dR4ZN5gl_Zqrj8M157fSQP4juvBx_iKThDTSc9a6tW9B9AesY-imV2zxLNNbFSrA9E6OXqEJweLSOa-ulJi_Tzs9LtYgg5l3WvuiR2FF5dI8c5JQsMEnrsDwp4hzBCevkp7JbUU-b25ZhSa6U",
      "e": "AQAB"
    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, again, I'm a complete beginner so I'm not sure if a private key is required alongside this to achieve what I'm after but I've done a fair bit of research and couldn't work out a solution so just thought I'd ask here...

Thanks!

Comment: "publicKey" most likely is one, [JSON](http://www.json.org)-encoded, and within this "n", "e" and I guess "prefix" are [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encoded (URL-safe variant), with "n" and "e" representing integers per big-endian convention (that encoding makes `e` the integer 65537 that is $2^{(2^4+1)}$, a very common choice, and `n` a 4096-bit integer with no obvious factor). Except that "Example output" is Base64-encoded (no variant), likely starts with "prefix" and perhaps is followed by an RSA ciphertext or signature, it's hard to tell. There should be specs somewhere!

Comment: @fgrieu hmm yes that is where I'm kind of stuck, can't really find anymore information other than RSA encrypting using that public key results in that "Example output". You mentioned that the publicKey is JSON-encoded, is there any way to decode (or convert) that into a regular publicKey?

Comment: There are many different "regular" RSA public key formats, especially when it comes to the ones that are text. Converting from one to another is not hard once you know the formats. In order to progress toward your goal _you_ need to gather context. If that includes `RS256`, [this](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518#section-3.3) tells it's [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#%5B%7B%22num%22:90,%22gen%22:0%7D,%7B%22name%22:%22XYZ%22%7D,118,721,null%5D) _signature_ (with SHA-256), _not_ encryption; but the example you gave is not consistent with that.